# How to make delay between each loops of jQuery.each function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, each

I have this-like code:

```
$('li').each(function(){
   var data = $(this).text();
   requestFunction(data, function(status){
       if ( status == 'OK' ) do stuff...
   });
});
```

So, i need to do some delay between using function "requestFunction()". How could i do this? Hope it understandable, thanks.

Comment: Yes, it was Google Maps Geocoder

Answer (score 26, accepted):

setTimeout at an increase time:

```
$('li').each(function(indexInArray){
   var data = $(this).text();
   setTimeout( function () {
       requestFunction(data, function(status){
           if ( status == 'OK' ) do stuff...
       });
   }, indexInArray * 500);
});
```

---

if you loop over these elements, we want to increase the timeout or else all the request would fire at the same time if not delayed, but only after our 500 ms timeout.

- Time Start: **0 ms**
- First Request: **0 ms (500 * 0)**
- Second Request: **500 ms (500 * 1)**
- Third Request: **1000 ms (500 * 2)**

Comment: What Array it would? I mean "indexInArray".

Comment: Oh, man, you just forget to write "each(function( *indexInArray* ){" this part of code. I know about index'es in jQ.each function. So, now i understad you well. Thanks. Will try it out.

Comment: @Ax, yeah, I had mistyped that. Let me know how it goes

Comment: Thanks man! It works well :D now Google Geocoder don't result with a status == "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"  :D Haha, thanks a lot :) But i make delay a little more for a good result id * 800

Answer (score 2):

If you're making ajax calls within your `each` loop then you may want to run the ajax requests syncronously.

To do this you can set the `async` property of the ajax request to `false`.

Alternatively you may want to look into implimenting a callback for `requestFunction`. This will allow you to run code after your method has returned and will negate the need for any timeout etc.

A callback is basically a method that gets executed at the end of your code. You basically tell your function, here's another function I want you to call when you've finished doing your work.

Comment: I can't attempt to read a source of "requestFunction". I just can make some delay between it calls.

Comment: Why do you need a delay between calls? Please explain

Comment: Yes. :) But i just wanna do it some pretty way. It would be ideal if it would be able to do delay between loops in jQ.each function.

Comment: Why do you want to do this thought? Please explain why. If you explain why, we may be able to help you more easily.

Comment: "A callback is basically a method that gets executed at the end of your code. You basically tell your function, here's another function I want you to call when you've finished doing your work."

Man, this is pretty stupid :) I know what is callback function :)

Comment: "Not understand, sory." - That is your first comment. I cannot read your mind Ax.

Comment: My first comment was for your first version of answer, without any edits. But, nevermind, i'm ok already. Thanks for help.

Comment: No problem. That's why I added the edit because I didn't know which bit you didn't understand. Glad you've got it sorted.

Comment: Thanks for a focus again. The function was Google.Map Geocode

Comment: was running into typical firefox aborting a slew of consecutive ajax requests and `sync: true` works.