# .each() is executing without any interval

Tags: jquery, settimeout, each

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.holder').each(function()
    {
        $(this).addClass('dummy');
        setTimeout( function () {
            $('.dummy').children('.box').slideDown('300');
        },2000);
    });
});
```

I have n number of `<div>` inside another `<div class='holder'>`. So I thought of adding some effects to each child `<div>`. But the problem is all the child `<div>` inside the holder is sliding down simultaneously. It seems it does not obey the `setTimeout()`. Why this happens?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445941/how-to-make-delay-between-each-loops-of-jquery-each-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `each` loop is executing about instantly, and you give the same timeout to all `setTimeout` calls. So they're all executed 2000 ms after the (instant) loop.

A simple solution :

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.holder').each(function(i){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.addClass('dummy');
        setTimeout( function () {
            $('.box', $this).slideDown('300');
        },2000*(i+1)); // give different timeouts
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But I need some more help. I saw the class 'dummy' is getting added to all the holder `<div>` first and then the slidedown happens. So still every child is getting slidedown simultaneously.

Comment: @SuryaS Your problem isn't really clear but does the edited version work for you ?

Comment: Thank you. I did a small typo :) Poor typing skill :@

Answer (score 2):

You need to increment the loop interval, also need to use the hodler reference inside the timeout callback

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('.holder').each(function (idx) {
        var $this = $(this).addClass('dummy');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $this.children('.box').slideDown('300');
        }, idx * 2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: @Riturajratan FYI it can be fixed much faster than finding that question and copying it

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('.holder').each(function (interval) { // interval here is index of each loop
        $(this).addClass('dummy');
        var $this = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $this.children('.box').slideDown('300');
        }, 2000 * (interval + 1));
    });
});
```

Explanation

```
1st timeOut = 2000=  2000 * (interval + 1)=  2000 * (0+ 1)=  2000 * (1)
2nd timeOut = 4000=  2000 * (interval + 1)=  2000 * (1+ 1)=  2000 * (2)
3rd timeOut = 6000=  2000 * (interval + 1)=  2000 * (2+ 1)=  2000 * (3)
```

and so on